# Is there a way to either capture unbound parameters or define a params-style overflow for query string parameters that are not strictly bound by name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Example:
(Request) GET `myapi/myaction?arg1=1&arg2=hello&extra1=35&extra2=banana`

then in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route...]
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(long arg1, string arg2, params KeyValuePair<string, string> others)
{
  ...expect others parameter to be an array of KVPs like [("extra1", "35"),("extra2", "banana")]
}
```

That's just for illustrative purposes. It doesn't work. You could write a custom model binder, or also use HttpContext to get access to the query string and do it that way but I was looking for a cleaner way to use the vanilla functionality of the framework if possible.

Comment: You can define the `others` as `string[]` which allows to send the multiple parameters in query string; with this approach, the the query string to invoke API will look like `myapi/myaction?arg1=1&arg2=hello&others=35&others=banana`. To access in code, you can use the array index.

Comment: @user1672994 unfortunately the key is important as well as the value. In my case, I want to know that extra1 is 35 and extra2 is banana. Using your suggestion we would only get the values.